# How do I create a local copy of a complete website section from OSX using curl?

Tags: osx, curl, recursive, download

I'm trying to download [Mathematics of the Discrete Fourier Transform](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mdft/)
 so that I can read through it off-line on my iPad (which doesn't have an Internet connection)

I have used `wget` in Linux. It seems that the OSX alternative is `curl`,  but I cannot find how to download recursively anywhere in the mammoth manual page.
Is this even the right tool for the job? If so, how to use it?

Comment: You'll find [here](http://psung.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-wget-or-curl-to-download-web.html) a way for curl to download more files in one command, but it seems it cannot download recursively as wget does.

Answer (score 2):

Curl will not download things for you recursively.  You'll need to install wget on your Mac.  The easiest way to do this is to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), which gives you access to a large repository of open source software, and the run:

```
port install wget
```

...and wait a bit.  This will install wget and all its prerequisites.