# How do I create a local copy of a complete website section from OSX using wget?

Tags: wget, recursive, mirror

This question follows from: [How do I create a local copy of a complete website section from OSX using curl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/how-do-i-create-a-local-copy-of-a-complete-website-section-from-osx-using-curl)

After discovering OSX's native curl wouldn't do this task I downloaded wget from here: http://www.techtach.org/wget-prebuilt-binary-for-mac-osx-lion

But performing:

```
./wget -r -l 0 https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mdft/
```

takes hours and installs a ton of other stuff I didn't want that ISN'T contained in this folder:

http://cl.ly/ENKr

Moreover opening a particular page, many of the images are missing:

http://cl.ly/ELXG

This may be because I aborted the transfer after a few hours(!)

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Your image links aren't inline-able.

Comment: @Mat, I will fix it as soon as I get 10 rep & gain the permission

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding:

```
--no-parent
```

*"Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded."*

In my experience it also prevents downloading from other sites.

Comment: That's great, thanks!   don't know why but it still contains some crud from parent http://cl.ly/EMoO  but all of the extra adds up to only a few k.