# How to create a http mirror?

Tags: http, mirror

I need to create a mirror of a directory shared over HTTP. Source server uses apache index module. Here is an example of a similar directory: http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/httpd/

The content is not available over FTP.

I can [use wget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32085/16253) to download the mirror recursively. The side effect is that in this case there are `index.html?....` files created.

I wonder if there is an utility which can do this easily, without need to cleanup destination directory manually?

Comment: `lftp` has a `mirror` command, and I have used to it mirror the Arch Linux repos. But you should see if there's some custom solution, like `apt-mirror`, before turning to options like `lftp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for mirror option for wget, -m.

```
wget -m http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Have you read the question?

Comment: Ahh dude, I should have let my test run finished. Sorry about that. How about ignoring '-R index.html*,foo,bar' and get them separately?